# SetLayoutParams null pointer execption

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am getting a null pointer exeption when im trying to debug my app. I think its becuse in my fragment onCreateView() method, container is null and when android.view.View.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams) is called there is an exeption. I dont know why container s null. I added the fragment to the activity in XML file and when i run the app in "run mode" the fragment is displayed in the activity. I only see this error when i try to debug.

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   // moviePosterFragment = new MoviePosterFragment();
    moviePosterFragment = (MoviePosterFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

   FetchMovies(1);

}
```

Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

android:id="@+id/container"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.example.user.popmovie.fragments.MoviePosterFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    mlayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),NUM_COLUMNS);


   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pop_movies_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mlayoutManager);
    //set adapter with empty data
    GridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getContext(),movieItemArray,mRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(GridAdapter);
  //  mProgressWheel = (ProgressWheel)  rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.progress);
   endlessScroll();
    Activity act =  getActivity();
    int a =0;
//      rootView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    if (container == null) {
        Log.i("in movieposterfragment", "onCreateView(): container = null");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("in movieposterfragment", "onCreateView(): container != null");
    }
    return rootView;


}
```

Fragment XML:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id = "@+id/fragment"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"


tools:context=".MoviePosterFragment">


<!-- Add a RecyclerView to fragment layout-->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/pop_movies_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Stack trace

```
03-06 20:33:20.675 27556-27556/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
03-06 20:33:20.675 27556-27556/? E/Zygote: v2
03-06 20:33:20.695 27556-27556/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.user.popmovie, PID: 27556
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.popmovie/com.example.user.popmovie.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:928)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:110)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.user.popmovie.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
03-06 20:34:57.049 27556-27556/com.example.user.popmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: The crash is in your activity's onCreate method, please share that code.

Comment: The exception is thrown by rootView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));?? That' s commented out in your code... please edit your post if necessary to include the offending lines of code that are not commented away.

Comment: please try clean and compile..before debug..

Comment: @Kevinze that code is commented out, i was trying to set the layout params manually see if the error went away but no luck

Comment: @cutcut oh okay. I don't really know what's causing the error, but maybe you can try shifting the bulk of the code within onCreateView to within onActivityCreated and see if that helps, since you are calling getActivity().

Comment: I ended up deleted the entire project after backing it up in my remote repo and pulled it in again and the error went away. Dont know why that worked or what the problem was but glad its working now :)